# SNMP - Decode Hex String Value Epson L395

Tags: printing, snmp, oid

This is my first question here, so hope it's correctly done.

Im trying to get some information from a Epson L365. The thing is when i try to get the Total page printed, I get the response in HEX-String

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.1248.1.2.2.1.1.1.4.1  0x40 42 44 43 20 53 54 32 0D 0A 62 00 01 01 04 06 02 01 00 0F 0D 03 01 00 69 03 01 69 04 02 69 05 03 69 10 03 01 09 4E 13 01 01 19 0C 00 00 00 00 00 75 6E 6B 6E 6F 77 6E 24 02 00 00 28 04 FF 01 00 00 2F 01 01 36 14 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF DB 2C 00 00 09 09 00 00 A0 00 00 00 37 05 02 00 00 00 00 40 0A 58 32 4E 5A 34 36 31 33 39 31 OctetString`

And this is the response that I get

`.1.3.6.1.4.1.1248.1.2.2.1.1.1.4.1  @BDC ST2 b......... ...i..i..i..i...    N..........unknown$...(...../..6..........,..       ......7......@ X2NZ461391  OctetString`

I have already researched and do not know where to go.

Comment: First you need the MIB documents from Epson in order to know what exactly is the data stored in `.1.3.6.1.4.1.1248.1.2.2.1.1.1.4.1`.

Comment: I didn't find anywhere. I've done a lot of research and I don't know how to get this information.

Comment: Contact the device vendor and ask for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Some data can be decoded by installing [epson_print_conf](https://github.com/Ircama/epson_print_conf#installation) and then running the following Python code:

```py
import epson_print_conf
import pprint
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")
printer = epson_print_conf.EpsonPrinter()
status = bytes.fromhex("""
40 42 44 43 20 53 54 32 0D 0A 62 00 01 01 04 06 02 01 00 0F 0D 03 01 00 69 03
01 69 04 02 69 05 03 69 10 03 01 09 4E 13 01 01 19 0C 00 00 00 00 00 75 6E 6B
6E 6F 77 6E 24 02 00 00 28 04 FF 01 00 00 2F 01 01 36 14 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
FF DB 2C 00 00 09 09 00 00 A0 00 00 00 37 05 02 00 00 00 00 40 0A 58 32 4E 5A
34 36 31 33 39 31
""")
decoded_status = printer.status_parser(status)
pprint.pprint(decoded_status)
```

Output:

```
Unaligned BDC ST2 header. Trying to fix...
Processing status - ftype 0x1, length: 1, item: 04
Processing status - ftype 0x6, length: 2, item: 01 00
Processing status - ftype 0xf, length: 13, item: 03 01 00 69 03 01 69 04 02 69 05 03 69
Processing status - ftype 0x10, length: 3, item: 01 09 4e
Processing status - ftype 0x13, length: 1, item: 01
Processing status - ftype 0x19, length: 12, item: 00 00 00 00 00 75 6e 6b 6e 6f 77 6e
Processing status - ftype 0x24, length: 2, item: 00 00
Processing status - ftype 0x28, length: 4, item: ff 01 00 00
Processing status - ftype 0x2f, length: 1, item: 01
Processing status - ftype 0x36, length: 20, item: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff db 2c 00 00 09 09 00 00 a0 00 00 00
Processing status - ftype 0x37, length: 5, item: 02 00 00 00 00
Processing status - ftype 0x40, length: 10, item: 58 32 4e 5a 34 36 31 33 39 31
>>> pprint.pprint(decoded_status)
{'cancel_code': 'No request',
 'ink_level': [(1, 0, 'Black', 'Black', 105),
               (3, 1, 'Cyan', 'Cyan', 105),
               (4, 2, 'Magenta', 'Magenta', 105),
               (5, 3, 'Yellow', 'Yellow', 105)],
 'jobname': 'Not defined',
 'loading_path': 'fixed',
 'maintenance_box_1': 'not full (0)',
 'maintenance_box_2': 'not full (0)',
 'maintenance_box_reset_count_1': 0,
 'maintenance_box_reset_count_2': 0,
 'paper_count_blank': 160,
 'paper_count_color': 11483,
 'paper_count_monochrome': 2313,
 'paper_count_normal': -1,
 'paper_count_page': -1,
 'paper_path': b'\x01\x00',
 'ready': True,
 'serial_number_info': 'X2NZ461391',
 'status': (4, 'Idle'),
 'unknown': [('0x24', b'\x00\x00'),
             ('0x28', b'\xff\x01\x00\x00'),
             ('0x2f', b'\x01')]}
```